# The expectation of the inverse of a negative binomial random variable?

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

Suppose $X \sim NB(n,p)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=x) = \binom{x-1}{n-1}p^n(1-p)^{x-n}$.
Then what is $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{X}) = \sum_{x=n}^\infty \frac{1}{x}\binom{x-1}{n-1}p^n(1-p)^{x-n}$?

Answer (score 5):

These negative moments of random variables are in general difficult to obtain closed-form expressions for. You already have $\text{E}[X^{-1}]$ in the form of an infinite series, but what you ultimately want is a representation as a finite sum or product. As I learned from my mentor, sometimes it is possible to get this using the generating function of $X$ as follows.

Let $G(z)=\text{E}[z^X]$ be the probability generating function of $X$. In this case, $X$ is negative binomial which yields
$$
G(z) = \text{E}[z^X] = \Big(\frac{pz}{1-\bar{p}z}\Big)^n
$$
with the short notation $\bar{p}=1-p$. Now observe that
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{G(z)}{z}\text{d}z = \int_0^1 \text{E}[z^{X-1}]\text{d}z = \text{E}\Big[\int_0^1 z^{X-1}\text{d}z\Big]= \text{E}\Big[\frac{1}{X}\Big]
$$
where switching the expectation operator and integral requires some regularity conditions to be fulfilled. I am quite sure in this case they are.
So
$$
\text{E}\Big[\frac{1}{X}\Big] = \int_0^1 \Big(\frac{pz}{1-\bar{p}z}\Big)^n \frac{\text{d}z}{z}
$$
For any finite value of $n$, the integrand is a rational function, so at least in principle it should be possible to integrate this analytically, giving a closed-form result.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28%28%28p*+z%29+%2F+%281%E2%88%92%281-p%29+*+z%29%29+%5E+n%29+%2F+z+dz+from+0+to+1) it contains both gamma and hypergeometric functions: $p\Gamma(n){_2}\tilde{F}{_1}(1, 1;n + 1;1 - p)$ for $\Re(n)>0 \land \Re(p)>0$

Answer (score 4):

In [this paper](https://oa.upm.es/4349/2/MENDO_ART_2006_01.pdf) (equation (3), derived in Appendix A) you can find a closed-form expression for that:

$$
\mathbb E \left[\frac 1 x \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{n-i} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^i +(-1)^n \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^n \ln p
$$

As noted in the paper  (see Appendix A), for $p$ close to $1$ numerical evaluation is easier if the logarithm is replaced by a certain series expansion.

Interestingly, the expression is much simpler (and is obtained more directly; see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4321610/91216)) if $1/x$ is replaced by $1/(x-1)$:

$$
\mathbb E \left[\frac 1 {x-1} \right] = \frac{p}{n-1}.
$$